# .htaccess redirection [subdomain] + add into file name

Tags: php, .htaccess, http, redirect, subdomain

I am trying to .htaccess redirect images/icon.png to images/[subdomain]_icon.png..

like:

```
demo.domain.com/images/icon.png to demo.domain.com/images/demo_icon.png
test.domain.com/images/icon.png to test.domain.com/images/test_icon.png
abc.domain.com/images/icon.png to abc.domain.com/images/abc_icon.png
```

redirection should be generic, not fixed.. any subdomain should be add with _icon.png..

```
[subdomain].domain.com/images/icon.png -> [subdomain].domain.com/images/[subdomain]_icon.png
```

Please advise..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.yourdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^images/icon\.png http://%1.yourdomain.com/images/%1_icon.png [R=301,L]
```

This example need to be tested...